# C# assign List<T>.Count minus one to integer does not work

Tags: c#, value-type

The following line of code confuses me:

```
int durationEventsCountMinusOne = (durationEvents.Count - 1);
```

the `durationEvents.Count` is equal to 1. Thus I assumed durationEventsCountMinusOne would become 0, but instead it stays one. I first had this bit of code in the initializer of a for statement.

I used the Visual Studio debugger, but could not find why it works this way. When I hover the `-1` when debugging it says 0; it just does not get assigned to the integer.

The code I am using, with some code left out

```
List<IEvent> durationEvents = new List<IEvent>();
while (currentEvent != null && currentEvent.Time <= (currentCalculation * secondsBetweenCalculations) / 60)
{
    // This runs once, because there is only one event in schedule.
    durationEvents.Add(currentEvent);
    currentEvent = Schedule.schedule.GetNextEvent();
}

// here durationEvents.Count is equal to 1, but using minus 1 behind it does not assign 0 to the durationEventsMinusOne
int durationEventsCountMinusOne = (durationEvents.Count-1);
for (int durationEventIndex = durationEvents.Count-1; durationEventIndex >= 0; durationEventIndex--)
{
    do stuff with duration event
}
```

Screenshot that shows the problem
[image: debugging]

**EDIT**
Same codebase works in Visual Studio Code, not in Visual Studio Community 2019

Comment: Can you share the context of this problem? Do you have a multiple threads in your application?

Comment: No this is it, when I create a new project and have this line of code in my main it behaves the same way.

Comment: Wtihout more code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer That's not possible because `durationEvents` is undeclared, post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Oke, give me a minute

Comment: I did not get the difference between `debugging` and `hovering` however if `durationEvents` is populated from different thread you can get it grows while debugging. It can one when code execution has stopped on breakpoint and two after next `step over` in the debugger. Could you please explain what is `durationEvents` and how is it populated with items ?

Comment: Are you debugging in Release?

Comment: The code works as expected. Something else is going in the code you didn't share. .Net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xNRjKV

Comment: @PatrickTucci We don't know, what is the `durationEvents`. It isn't possible to understand the problem without details and context of this code

Comment: You can see the example has a list<t>

Comment: It is extremely likely (but not impossible) that you have found a bug in the CLR, compiler, whatever, that causes such a problem. Much more likely is that you're observing incorrect state because you're debugging a release, or you think the count is 1 when it really is 2, or plenty of other possible causes. You said a new project had the same problem, can you create a complete [mcve] so we can test it with the same code and output you got?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am trying to recreate it. I can upload some prt screens so you can see I am debuggin in the correct mode and the .Count() is indeed giving 1

Comment: You set to `durationEventsCountMinusOne` but not use it. A release build could optimize it out. If you are running the debugger on a release build, I won't be surprised that you would not see the value assigned... because it didn't assign it, because it was optimized, because it is not used.

Comment: @Theraot I am using debug mode, I also use the same statement in the for loop beneath it which had the problem first.

Comment: `.Count()` is giving 1, are you using `.Count` (property of the list) or `.Count()` extension method from LINQ? They should return the same value, but since you mention the parenthesis, are you sure we're seeing your actual code in the question?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer if it is a debug build (see build configuration of your project), then I have no idea what is going on. And yes, I saw the same expression in the for, yet it does not use the variable.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen my bad, I am indeed using Count not Count()

Comment: @Theraot I thought it had something to do with the for loop, so i created an integer which then showed the same issue

Comment: I'd like to see a screenshot of the debugger showing that `durationEvents.Count` is `1` and `durationEventsCountMinusOne` is also `1`.

Comment: @MattU screenshot added

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen see screenshot, I really don't get why it won't assign

Comment: @Theraot see screenshot

Comment: It looks like the code is currently stopped *on* that line, can you step over it and re-examine the variable? Also try to add `Console.WriteLine(durationEventsCountMinusOne);` after that line, to rule out that the debugger is confused (which it sometimes is)

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer where is the next instruction to execute there (usually highlighted in yellow)? Is it on the same line? - I'm wondering if there is some other code that could have removed an item from `durationEvents`. Etiher after `durationEventsCountMinusOne` was set, or concurrently (see others were asking about threads). Edit: I do not really think that is the case, yet, I don't really know what the case is.

Comment: I removed everything below and in the for loop, so nothing gets deleted. Also the same code runs on with different IDE and compiler

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to debug the code in the VS debugger. Try to add debug prints before and after the executed statements. That will show you the real picture. 
Add Console.WriteLine(...) if your app is console app, if no, add Debug.Print(...)
Based on my experience you'll see the issue right away after looking at the print outs

List durationEvents = new List();
    while (currentEvent != null && currentEvent.Time <= (currentCalculation * secondsBetweenCalculations) / 60)
    {
        // This runs once, because there is only one event in schedule.
        durationEvents.Add(currentEvent);
        currentEvent = Schedule.schedule.GetNextEvent();
    }

```
// here durationEvents.Count is equal to 1, but using minus 1 behind it does not assign 0 to the durationEventsMinusOne
Console.WriteLine(durationEvents.Count);
Console.WriteLine(durationEvents.Count  - 1);
int durationEventsCountMinusOne = (durationEvents.Count-1);
Console.WriteLine(durationEventsCountMinusOne);
for (int durationEventIndex = durationEvents.Count-1; durationEventIndex >= 0; durationEventIndex--)
{
    do stuff with duration event
}
```